# How many different terms are there in the expansion of $(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m)^n$ after all terms with identical sets of exponents are added?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I just can't understand how to go about it!

Comment: You need to count the number of solutions of $d_1+d_2+...+d_m=n$ for $d_i\geq 0$ integers. Each solution corresponds to one term $x_1^{d_1}x_2^{d_2}...x_m^{d_m}$ in the expansion. Use this combinatorial technique: [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) applied to the equivalent problem $d_1'+...+d_m'=m+n$, $d_i'>1$, with $n+m$ the number of stars, and $m$ the number of bars. Interpret the number of starts between two bars to be the value of one of the $d_i'$.

Answer (score 0):

As user545963 has commented, each pattern involves $m$ non-negative integer exponents adding up to $n$.  The number of compositions of this form can be found with *stars and bars* $(n$ stars and $m-1$ bars separating them into $m$ values$)$ so $${n+m-1 \choose n} \text{ possible patterns of the exponents}$$

You can also express the coefficient of each $x_1^{d_1}x_2^{d_2}\cdots x_m^{d_m}$ pattern: it is $\dfrac{n!}{d_1!\,d_2!\,\cdots d_m!}$ and if you add these all up you get the unsurprising answer of $m^n$